# My genetic algorithm in last generation not improve fitness score

Tags: python, optimization, genetic-algorithm

I write simple genetic algorithm, the code is show below

Fitness function is define as

```py
def fitness(a, b, c, d, e):
    return a**2 + b**2 + c**2 + d**2 + e**2
```

function to generate first population

```py
def generate_pop(numInd, numGene):
    population = []
    for i in range(numInd):
        individual = [random.uniform(-10, 10) for _ in range(numGene)]
        population.append(individual)
    return population
```

Selection and cross over function

```py
def randomCrossover(population):
    offspring = []
    for i in range(len(population)//2):
        Ind1_index = random.randint(0, len(population)-1)
        Ind2_index = random.randint(0, len(population)-1)
        while Ind2_index == Ind1_index:
            Ind2_index = random.randint(0, len(population)-1)

        Ind1 = population[Ind1_index]
        Ind2 = population[Ind2_index]

        crossPoint = random.randint(1, len(Ind1))
        child1 = Ind1[:crossPoint] + Ind2[crossPoint:]
        child2 = Ind2[:crossPoint] + Ind1[crossPoint:]
        offspring.append(child1)
        offspring.append(child2)
    return offspring
```

Conclude all function in this function

```py
def geneticAlgorithm(mutation=0.1, numGeneration=100):
    population = generate_pop(12, 5)
    maxFitnessScoreGen = []
    minFitnessScoreGen = []
    avgFitnessScoreGen = []
    for _ in range(numGeneration):
        fitScore = [fitness(a, b, c, d, e) for a, b, c, d, e in population]
        maxFitnessScoreGen.append(max(fitScore))
        minFitnessScoreGen.append(min(fitScore))
        avgFitnessScoreGen.append(mean(fitScore))
        # population = [population[i] for i in range(len(population)) if fitness[i] == min(fitness)] # should individual that have lowest fitness score
        
        offspring = randomCrossover(population)
            
        for i in range(len(offspring)):
            if random.uniform(0, 1) < mutation:
                offspring[i] = [random.uniform(-10, 10), random.uniform(-10, 10), random.uniform(-10, 10), random.uniform(-10, 10), random.uniform(-10, 10)]

        population = offspring
        # print(f'gen {_} maxScore = {maxFitnessScoreGen}, avgScore = {avgFitnessScoreGen}')
        # print(population)

    return maxFitnessScoreGen, minFitnessScoreGen ,avgFitnessScoreGen
```

But the result of the optimization is oscillate and seem like to not improving. I have no idea what I'm I doing wrong with my code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the chance for a member of the population to participate in reproduction must be in some way tied to the fitness - fitter individuals have higher chance of reproducing. But your randomCrossover function just randomly chooses members of the population, regardless of fitness.

What you need to do is sample the population in a way such that not everyone has the same chance to be selected.

You can probably figure this out on your own, but I'll show anyway how I think the sampling should work (modified Java/pseudocode from [here](https://github.com/kutschkem/Jayes/blob/master/plugins/org.eclipse.recommenders.jayes/src/org/eclipse/recommenders/jayes/sampling/BasicSampler.java#L46-L57)):

```
   int sampleFromPopulation(fitnessArray) { 
       double[] probs = normalize(fitnessArray); // normalize so sum of fitness values is 1 -> gives a probability distribution
        double currentProb = 0;
        int individualToBeChosen= 0;
        double rand = random.nextDouble();
        for (double prob : probs) {   // add up probabilities until you reach the random value
            currentProb += prob;
            if (rand < currentProb) {
                break;
            }
            individualToBeChosen++;
        }
        return Math.min(individualToBeChosen, fitnessArray.length()- 1);
}
```